# Advanced ways to improve battery life for Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, laptop, battery, battery-life

I've noticed that going from Windows 8.1 to windows 10 I've lost a lot of battery life. Talking about hours worth.

Are there any tricks other then the basic common sense like battery saver, power options, bluetooth, wireless, ect...

I've removed all the store applications and Apps in general that like to just run in the background and waste life, but are there any other options?

I'm running version 1607.

Answer (score 2):

[Windows 10 includes a component](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/shows/defrag-tools/157-energy-estimation-engine-e3) called `Energy Estimation Engine (E3)` which monitors the energy consumption in Windows.

Run `powercfg /srumutil` in a cmd.exe, started as admin, to generate a report which can be [analyzed in Excel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/shows/defrag-tools/157-energy-estimation-engine-e3#time=09m07s) and look if you can see which component uses so much energy.

Comment: Wow nice! I only thought linux had stuff like this.